# How to use ContinueWith properly when the other task may continue running forever?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, continuewith

How to use `ContinueWith` properly when there is a chance that the other task may continue running forever?

### Example:

`task` is infinite but I'm only would like to wait for her only for specific amount of time:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
{
    //Small chance for infinite loop
});

task.ContinueWith(t => {
    //We would still like to get here after a certion amount of time eventualy.
});
```

Comment: Short answer is you don't... it doesn't make any sense, if you want a possible never-ending-task and you want to `ContinueWith`, then you don't have the right tool for the job

Comment: @Saruman but i want to protect myself not to wait forever

Comment: How exactly are you using the `.ContinueWith` here ? Do you check the `t` for error or just want to execute some business logic ?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/11/10/crafting-a-task-timeoutafter-method/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run another Task.Delay to wait

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
        {
            //Small chance for infinite loop
        });
        var delayTask = Task.Delay(2000); // A wait task 
        Task.WhenAny(delayTask,task).ContinueWith((t) =>
        {
            //check which task has finished 
        });
```

But you should use a way to stop First Task Some How timeout it or use 
[CancellationTokenSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_CancellationTokenSource__ctor_System_TimeSpan_)

Comment: And one thread from thread pool may work forever if you don't care. Sometimes I suspect my OS works the same way. :)

Comment: @AccessDenied you are right I update the answer

Comment: The place of ContinueWith is change so it will run after "task" finish or "delayTask" finish whichever happend first